# how to style react child component under standard HTML element?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm learning react and while doing projects came across this situation.

I've below scenario where 2 react child components are under standard HTML element

In case I need to target and style individual react child element how to do it ?

In case of normal HTML elements; I would have assigned `className` to each individual `child HTML element` and styled them.

But this approach doesn't work with `react component`, please suggest how to handle it ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can style you react component easily with adding className attribute to them and then in a seprate css file write some stylesheets to style them.

1-first import your css file in you components (e.g. App.jsx or App.js ):

```
import './index.css'
```

2- give a className to each components:

```
<div className="testClass" > </div>
```

your css file is something like this:

```
    .testClass {
      width : 100px;
      height : 100px;
      background-color: red;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div className='parent'>
        <h1 className='one'>
          Text 1
        </h1>
        <p className='two'>
          Text 2
        </p>
        <div
          className='three'
        >
          <div className='three-one' >
            one
          </div>
          <div className='three-two' >
            trwo
          </div>
       </div>
 </div>
```

Now you can add a file as 'style.css' and import it in this component as

```
import '.style.css';
```

and add styling inside style.css as you do in normal HTML/CSS. Or you can add styling as

```
<div style={{ backgroundColor: '#000', border: '1px solid #eee'  }}> one </div>
```

Or you can use CSS modules / styled-components. There are many ways to add styling.

[How to add styling in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html)